# Convert json schema to xsd

Tags: java, json, xsd

I am looking for a way to convert json schema into xsd using some java library.

I have tried https://github.com/ethlo/jsons2xsd.

But is there any other library or standard approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain why jsons2xsd was not suitable. What are your requirements? What is your overall objective?

Comment: jsons2xsd works but I just want to check that if there is any other standard library or approach.